# Change values on form submit?

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with two different sets of fields in  a form, one is billing address and one is shipping address.

I have written some jQuery so that you can hide the shipping form and it fills it in with the details in the billing form (if you are shipping to the same address).

This is my jQuery:

```
$('#reveal-shipping').click(function(){
    if( $('.wpsc_checkout_table.table-2').css('display') == 'none' ){

        $('.wpsc_checkout_table.table-2').slideToggle();
        $('.wpsc_checkout_table.table-2').find('input, select, textarea').val('');
        document.getElementById('reveal-shipping').innerHTML = 'Ship to my billing address &larr;';

    } else {

        //fields is an array containing an array of two selector strings, one for the billing form and one for the shipping.
        for ( i=0; i < fields.length; i++ ){
            thisval = $(fields[i][0]).val();
            $(fields[i][1]).val( thisval );
        }
        $('.wpsc_checkout_table.table-2').slideToggle();
        document.getElementById('reveal-shipping').innerHTML = 'Ship to a different address &rarr;';

    }
});
```

I'm wondering if I can run the for loop, which is the part that fills in the hidden input elements with values, onClick of the submit button, or if the values would have already been submitted by this point.

If not, when would be a good time to run this to ensure that the values are submitted correctly? maybe onunfocus? (please tell me the actual name for this)

Thanks in advance

Comment: on change or on keyup on billing input you update corresponding  shipping input -> no loop

Comment: @mikakun Sounds like a good idea but I will still use the loop aswell as when I reveal the shipping I clear them, and if they were edited, then hidden and the billing isn't edited again it will be inaccurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be able to do this on the `onClick` event of the submit button or you can register a `submit` event on the form.  Your events are run before the rest of the submission takes place.  This is why you can call validation methods on the form and interrupt the submission by returning the value `false`.

The 'onunfocus' event you are thinking of is `blur`

Comment: Thanks. can you give me very basic example? I didn't understand the bit about interrupting the submission by returning false? Thanks again.

Comment: Suppose rather than filling the values, you wanted to make sure that the shipping address inputs were filled in, you can have your `onClick` function check that the fields are not empty.  If you find one, then if you `return false` it will not continue with submitting the form or completing the click event.